# How to print rows with a cell value smaller than 0.2 in any of the columns?

Tags: csv, awk

I have a csv file with 100+ columns and 1000+ rows (myfile.csv), and I need to print the header and every row with a cell value smaller than 0.2 in **at least one** column (regardless of which column) to a new file (newfile_0.2.csv). I do need the entire row.

I can only find ways of doing this for a [specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556923/how-to-grep-rows-that-have-value-less-than-0-2-in-a-specific-column).

This is my list of unsuccessful attempts (I am very new to coding):

```
awk '(NR==1) || ($0 < 0.2 ) ' myfile.csv > newfile_0.2.csv

awk -F "," 'BEGIN $0 < 0.2 {print $0}' myfile.csv > newfile_0.2.csv

awk -F "," '{OFS = ","} BEGIN {$0 < 0.2} {print $0}' myfile.csv > newfile_0.2.csv

awk '{FS = ","} {OFS = ","} BEGIN {$0 < 0.2} {print $0}' myfile.csv > newfile_0.2.csv

awk -F "," '{if ($0 < 0.2) print $0}' myfile.csv > newfile_0.2.csv

while read line; do awk -F "," '{if ($0 < 0.2) print $0}' line ; done < myfile.csv > newfile_0.2.csv

while read line; do echo $line | awk -F "," '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i < 0.2) print $i}'; done < myfile.csv > newfile_0.2.csv
```

Would anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: The entire row may be access with `$0`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your efforts I did this sketch:

```
# file: script.awk
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
{ # for every row
  hit = 0 ; for (i = 1; i <= NF && !hit; ++i) { if ($i < 0.2) hit = 1 }
  if (hit) print $0
  next
}
```

Sample session (cygwin, bash, gawk):

```
$ cat >myfile.csv <<EOF
> 1,1,1,1
> 1,0.1,1,1
> 2,2,2,2
> 0,1,2,3
> 3,3,3,3.0
> EOF

$ awk -f script.awk myfile.csv
1,0.1,1,1
0,1,2,3
```

Maybe, you have to ensure a compatible LOCALE.
Thus

```
$ LANG=C
```

could be a good idea in case.

Playing around with this I got this (even shorter) version:

```
# file: script.awk
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
{ # for every row
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { if ($i < 0.2) { print $0 ; break } }
}
```

which passed my test file as well.

...or finally reduced as "one-liner":

```
$ awk -F , -v OFS=, '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { if ($i < 0.2) { print $0 ; break } } }' test-filter-0.2.txt
1,0.1,1,1
0,1,2,3
```

Comment: @pdalcinmartins I'm not sure wether the `next` is really necessary. However, I'm sure it does not hurt...

Comment: You may want to the set the `OFS=","` too

Comment: @pdalcinmartins Thus, the `next` is not needed i.e. rows which does not match any rule are simply consumed. (What I remembered is actually the behavior of `lex`/`flex` which simply reflects any non-matching pattern to `yyout`.)